# PHP - Insert unknown number of rows into MySQLi database from Array?

Tags: php

so I'm a little stuck. Ultimately I'm trying to insert an unknown number of records into a database depending on how many the user specifies. To make it more complicated, I'm using a number of arrays. In real world terms, I'm trying to allow users to specify each bedrooms/baths that each unit has in their apartment building. A building may have 1 unit or 20 units if it's a large apartment complex.

**Unit 1: (Row 1)**

```
<select name="numberbedrooms[]">
  <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
  <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
  <option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option>
</select>
<select name="numberbathrooms[]">
  <option value="1">1 Bathroom</option>
  <option value="2">2 Bathrooms</option>
  <option value="3">3 Bathrooms</option>
</select>
<textarea name="unitdetails[]"></textarea>
```

**Unit 2** (Row 2)

```
<select name="numberbedrooms[]">
      <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option>
    </select>
    <select name="numberbathrooms[]">
      <option value="1">1 Bathroom</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bathrooms</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bathrooms</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="unitdetails[]"></textarea>
```

**Unit 3** (Row 3)

```
<select name="numberbedrooms[]">
      <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option>
    </select>
    <select name="numberbathrooms[]">
      <option value="1">1 Bathroom</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bathrooms</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bathrooms</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="unitdetails[]"></textarea>
```

**...and so on for a potentially unlimited number of units...**

All I'm really trying to do INSERT this information into my MySQLi table, but I'm not very strong with Arrays:

```
$unitsTable = "listing_unit_info";
$insertUnitsSQL = "INSERT INTO $unitsTable (num_of_beds, num_of_baths, unit_details) VALUES (numberbedrooms[], numberbathrooms[], unitdetails[])";
mysqli_query($con, $insertUnitsSQL);
```

I think this really comes down to my lack of Array skills. I think I'm looking for some fancy footwork with *foreach()* and *implode()*. I would test these, but I'm afraid of screwing up the DB. Also, please don't comment on SQL injection - this is a simplified version and I'm aware of the implications. Thanks!

Comment: _“I would test these, but I'm afraid of screwing up the DB”_ – well then test on a _copy_ of the existing table instead of the real one …

Comment: True, should have thought of that.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would down-vote this question - it's 100% a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$unitsTable = "listing_unit_info";
$count = is_array($_POST['numberbedrooms']) ? count($_POST['numberbedrooms']) : 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $num_of_beds = empty($_POST['numberbedrooms'][$i]) ? 0 : intval($_POST['numberbedrooms'][$i]);
    $num_of_baths = empty($_POST['numberbathrooms'][$i]) ? 0 : intval($_POST['numberbathrooms'][$i]);
    $unit_details = empty($_POST['unitdetails'][$i]) ? 0 : intval($_POST['unitdetails'][$i]);

    ...

    // better use `prepare` outside of the loop and `execute` inside
    // and yes, better use parameters `?, ?, ?`
    $insertUnitsSQL = "INSERT INTO $unitsTable (num_of_beds, num_of_baths, unit_details) VALUES ($num_of_beds, $num_of_baths, $unit_details)";
    mysqli_query($con, $insertUnitsSQL);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "for" instead of "foreach"? I'm getting an error on that line.

Comment: It's wierd, for some reason this is setting my session to "1" which is messing up other functionality, but I'm not sure how. Once I logout and log back in, it's normal. Only after submitting the update information does it happen. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final result - I just wanted to post a simplified answer in case anyone has a similar problem in the future. I put this together after considering **Axalix**'s answer.

The HTML  fields basically already declared the array variables.

```
$beds       = $_POST['unitbedrooms'];
$baths      = $_POST['unitbathrooms'];
$details    = $_POST['unitdetails'];
$propertyid = $_GET['propertyid']; //This input is static.
```

Now it's just a matter of putting each row into the database:

```
foreach ($beds as $key => $n) {
    $addUnitSQL = "INSERT INTO $unitsTable (listing_id, num_of_beds, num_of_baths, unit_details) VALUES ('$propertyid', '$n', '$baths[$key]', '$details[$key]')";
    mysqli_query($con, $addUnitSQL);
}
```

Generally, I like to keep my code as simple as possible, so I narrowed my code down to this. Please keep in mind, this code is prone to SQL injection, so be sure to clean your inputs if you choose to use this code.